# How to extract data based on monthly wise for the certain period of time using python Data Frame

Tags: python

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start='2019-07-01', end='2020-06-30')})
df['Date'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period("M"))
df
```

I have tried:

```
df[['Date ', 'Sector ', 'Total']].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Datel', freq='M')).sum()
```

Comment: Please add more context. Simply stating code isn't useful for anyone who's trying to figure out your problem.

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this  question

Comment: If you want anyone to help you, you actually need to tell us what the problem is. Have you had a try yet? Show us some code.

Comment: my output must be containing all data with the aforementioned condition

Comment: df[['Date ', 'Sector ', 'Total']].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Datel', freq='M')).sum() i have tried this code

Comment: I haven't used this before, but I think the `df.between_time()` could be used here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html